# Checking if a dataset is complete using another dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

Context: I have one `dataset_A` that tells me what content I should find in the `dataset_B`. So basically each version in `dataset_A` contains multiple `code_id`s with various catogories that should all appear in `dataset_B`. It might be possible that some categories get delivered later to `dataset_B`. If everything is complete, I execute a code (irrelevant what it does), if not, I wait.

```
dataset_A=

version      code_id     characteristics     category_1     category_2  
      1         2344         abc_def_ghi           beta          three
      1         3435         abc_def_ghh          alpha            one
      2         5666         abc_def_ghh          alpha            two
 ...

dataset_B=

code_id        characteristics       category_1       category_2      values
   2344            abc_def_ghi             beta            three         757
   3435            abc_def_ghh            alpha              one         875
...
```

My idea:
So, "manually" I would look at my `dataset_B` `code_id`, look it up in `dataset_A`, see what `categories` I am supposed to find for that code (version is also important) and go back to `dataset_A` to check if it is complete. I have to run the subsequent code if the dataset is complete, and raise an exception (instead of abort it) if it is incomplete, so that it waits a bit until the next build is run and hopefully the data is complete by then.

My question is how do I check for completeness? Is it enough to do a join (outer join?) and see what rows are missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `leftanti` join to see if there are some rows in df1 but not in df2, that is `df.join(df2, on='key-to-join', how='leftanti')`

Comment: Whereby the key-to-join is the column group of categories and characteristics, is that correct?

Comment: @johnnydoe In your case you just want to check if the `code_id` in dataset_B all appear in dataset_A right? If yes, you can do `dataset_B.join(dataset_A, on='code_id', how='leftanti')` to see which code_id is in dataset_B but not in A

Comment: not just that. Dataset_A says: for each "characteristics" there are these n versions for which these categories have to be delivered. In Dataset_B I ask myself: have all the categories for each of the *characteristics" been already delivered?